# Is there a WPF Typewriter effect?

Tags: wpf, animation, effect

Is there any equivalent to Flash's Typewriter effects in WPF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I made it work!

```
private void TypewriteTextblock(string textToAnimate, TextBlock txt, TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
        story.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
        story.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

        DiscreteStringKeyFrame discreteStringKeyFrame;
        StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames stringAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        stringAnimationUsingKeyFrames.Duration = new Duration(timeSpan);

        string tmp = string.Empty;
        foreach(char c in textToAnimate)
        {
            discreteStringKeyFrame = new DiscreteStringKeyFrame();
            discreteStringKeyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.Paced;
            tmp += c;
            discreteStringKeyFrame.Value = tmp;
            stringAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(discreteStringKeyFrame);
        }
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(stringAnimationUsingKeyFrames, txt.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(stringAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath(TextBlock.TextProperty));
        story.Children.Add(stringAnimationUsingKeyFrames);

        story.Begin(txt);
    }
```

But is there a way to have the characters fade in?

Comment: For a follow-up question best start a new separate question. More people would see it and try to answer if you post it as
a question on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

By typewriter effects you mean the string being displayed letter by letter?

You can achieve similar effect with [StringAnimationUsingKeyframes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stringanimationusingkeyframes.aspx) object, however, you would have to enter every string value manually.

To create this effect automatically, you would have to write your own animation object, most likely one based on [StringAnimationBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stringanimationbase.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! With that I was able to do what I posted as answer.

Comment: Fading in: I guess that's most likely not possible with strings, you would have to take completely new approach. Make a WrapPanel and add a TextBlock with letter to it every N milliseconds (you can use DispatcherTimer). Then you can use DoubleAnimation class to simply make every letter fade in over a time period (animate the OpacityProperty). This is however not going to be very effective on longer strings!